# What's the difference between -n and -g in sort?

Tags: bash, sorting

According to the man page, the `-n` option compares by "string numerical value", and `-g` compares by "general numerical value". What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the source code, here are the three numeric sorts:

- numeric: Handle strings of digits with optional decimal                           point, but no exponential notation.
- general_numeric: Handle numbers in exponential notation, also handle hex, infinity, .. (cf man strtold)
- human_numeric: sorting by human readable units with either SI or IEC prefixes.

Here are exemples:

```
$ sort /tmp/tosort-gen   
0
0x0a
1
100
1e1
1e2
1k
1M
2e3
INF

$ sort -h /tmp/tosort-gen
0
0x0a
INF
1
1e1
1e2
2e3
100
1k
1M

$ sort -g /tmp/tosort-gen
0
1
1k
1M
0x0a
1e1
100
1e2
2e3
INF
```

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, see "...have already been asked and answered many times before" as one of the categories to avoid in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section.